# How to translate this php query into mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to use this query to get the data using the mysql

```
$this->db->select("ii.id,oi.user_id as uid,oi.id as oid")->from("order_info oi")->join("iform_info ii","oi.id = ii.order_id")->where("oi.order_no",$id)->get()->row_array();
```

I was thinking something like this

```
SELECT * FROM `order_info` JOIN(iform_info) WHERE `order_id` = '1'
```

Comment: Please post the result of your MySQL query and tell us what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I was just trying to use the same query the php is using to get the same result using navicat or mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$this->db->select("ii.id,oi.user_id as uid,oi.id as oid")->from("order_info oi")->join("iform_info ii","oi.id = ii.order_id")->where("oi.order_no",$id)->get()->row_array();
```

**converts to**

```
SELECT ii.id, oi.user_id as uid, oi.id as oid
FROM order_info oi JOIN iform_info ii ON oi.id = ii.order_id 
WHERE oi.order_no = $id
```

You can use this SELECT query in your PHP code and pass `$id` dynamically.